# Meaning of 緑色 in this passage

Tags: translation

I have a question about the meaning of 緑色 in the following sentence. Does the author means a green colored bug by it, or the nature itself?

Translation attempt: "Ferocious 'green colored' will caught the butterfly."

> 緑色の狂暴な意志が、蝶を捕まえていた。

[Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRuPU.jpg)

Comment: Just a note: the kanji in your image reads 狂暴, not 凶暴.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former:

[image]

[(taken from here)](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/bbutterfly/e/c2659d9af14ecf5a16d942a31e6b8892)

It doesn't say so explicitly, but the description reads a lot like a カマキリ, mantis.